# docker-compose error when creating MySQL database container

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` in my Spring Boot app but when I run `docker-compose up -d`, I get the following error:

> "failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount967315702/Dockerfile: no such file or directory"

As I use **Windows10**, I think I need some tweaks related to the WORKDIR, etc. I have WSL where Docker installed). But even I tried different combinations, I have not managed to fix the problem.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` in my root project folder (`springboot-backend`):

***docker-compose.yml:*** I am not sure about

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
    ports:
      - $MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  app:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build: ./springboot-backend
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - $SPRING_LOCAL_PORT:$SPRING_DOCKER_PORT
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
        "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT/$MYSQLDB_DATABASE?useSSL=false",
        "spring.datasource.username" : "$MYSQLDB_USER",
        "spring.datasource.password" : "$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD",
        "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
      }'
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
volumes:
  db:
```

***Dockerfile:***

```
FROM maven:3.8.2-jdk-8
WORKDIR /springboot-backend
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean install
CMD mvn spring-boot:run
```

***.env file:***

```
MYSQLDB_USER=root
MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=******
MYSQLDB_DATABASE=employee_management_system
MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT=3307
MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT=3306
SPRING_LOCAL_PORT=6868
SPRING_DOCKER_PORT=8080
```

Any idea?

Here is folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Where did you put your Dockerfile? Maybe you can share you project folder structure.

Comment: Can you try to put docker-compose.yaml outside of springboot-backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build: ./springboot-backend
```

Docker compose yaml try to build springboot-backend but there is no such directory in the same path of compose yaml. Just simply you can move docker-compose yaml to outside of springboot-backend project folder.

Comment: Yes, you right. But instead of moving it o outside of the project folder, what about creating a new folder and move to it? Or something like that? BEcause I need to keep these files in my project folder as you know.

Comment: Sure it works as well

Comment: What about `WORKDIR` in the `Dockerfile` ?`

Comment: I use `build: ./` and `WORKDIR /springboot-backend` and then it worked. Thanks a lot Amigo Gürkan.